# concat list of project by project_type and status using string_agg

Tags: postgresql

I work with postgresql 11

I have a table named **project_type** contains this value :

```
id    lbl

1     Research
2     Business
3     Maintenance
```

and I have a table named : **technical_project** which have this data :

```
    id  name  status      project_type

    1   test1 open        1
    2   test2 open        1
    3   test3 inProgress  2
    4   test4 inProgress  1
    5   test5 closed      2
    6   test6 inProgress  2
```

I want to have in one query : concat the list of all project type and for each status concat the count of technical_projec by project type.

this is the output of query that I want to have :

```
[Research,Business,Maintenance], open  ,[2,0,0] ,inProgress  ,[1,2,0] ,closed  ,[0,1,0]
```

or like this :

```
[Research,Business,Maintenance] ,[2,0,0]  ,[1,2,0]  ,[0,1,0]
```

meaning for the status open it has 2 project with type Research , 0 project with type Business , 0 project with type Maintenance

the status open , inProgress and closed are fixed and project_type are dynamic that why should be read from table project_type .

I think that I should use **string_agg**

can someone help me to find the correct query

Comment: don't know did you see the new code that I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 14.04.2022**

Made in my opinion a more efficient solution. I'll leave a link to the old version (where there are a lot of subqueries). The main idea is to do a `merge` by grouping by `status, i.id` and then count the number where it is `not zero`.

```
SELECT COUNT(status), status, i.id
FROM project_type AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN technical_project AS c
ON i.id = c.project_type
WHERE  status != ''
GROUP BY status, i.id
;
```

what gives:

```
 count |   status   | id
-------+------------+----
     2 | inProgress |  2
     1 | inProgress |  1
     1 | closed     |  2
     2 | open       |  1
```

In `WITH vars_null` I create a dummy table filled with `id` and `status`.
I connect `vars_null` with the result of the `subquery` by i.id = q.id and i.status = q.status. And through COALESCE I set 0 to `q.count`, where there are no values.

And using array_agg I create arrays by removing array_remove NULL values.
Connecting everything with: `||','||`

All code:

```
SELECT 
(
SELECT array_agg(lbl)::text FROM project_type)||','||
array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN r.status = 'open' THEN r.cou END), NULL)::text||','||
array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN r.status = 'inProgress' THEN r.cou END), NULL)::text||','||
array_remove(array_agg(CASE WHEN r.status = 'closed' THEN r.cou END), NULL)::text AS row
FROM
(
WITH vars_null as (
(select 'open' as status, * from generate_series(1, 3) as id)
UNION ALL
(select 'inProgress' as status, * from generate_series(1, 3) as id)
UNION ALL
(select 'closed' as status, * from generate_series(1, 3) as id)
)

SELECT i.id, COALESCE(q.count,0) AS cou, i.status
FROM vars_null AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( 
SELECT COUNT(status), status, i.id
FROM project_type AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN technical_project AS c
ON i.id = c.project_type
WHERE  status != ''
GROUP BY status, i.id
)
AS q
ON i.id = q.id and i.status = q.status
ORDER BY i.status, i.id
) r
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B2cKf7oC) is the old code where there are a lot of subqueries.